# Odoo 10 view inherit error with fleet

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10

here is my view.xml

```
 <record model='ir.ui.view' id='fleet_vehicle_parc_form'>
        <field name="name">fleet.vehicle.form</field>
        <field name="model">fleet.vehicle</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="fleet.fleet_vehicle_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
...
```

When I install the module, an error appears:

```
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: fleet.fleet_vehicle_form"
```

Though I have already add 'fleet' to my dependancy in manifest.py

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: make sure there exist form view `fleet_vehicle_form` in module `fleet`.

Comment: And add dependency in `__manifest__.py` file, like `'depends':['fleet']`

Comment: oh thank you. It is fleet_vehicle_view_form in Odoo v10 instead of fleet_vehicle_form. I used to use Odoo v9. Thank you KbiR